# How to pass function that converts to interface{}

Tags: go

I'm trying to write a function that would open a file, build an object out of each line using another function it receives as parameter and return a slice of these objects, similar to this:

```
func readFile(filename string, transform func(string) interface {}) (list []interface {}) {
    if rawBytes, err := ioutil.ReadFile(filename); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    } else {
        lines := strings.Split(string(rawBytes), "\n")
        for i := range lines {
             t := transform(lines[i])
             list = append(list, t)
        }
    }
    return list
}
```

I've tried to use it like this:

```
func transform(line string) (myObject *MyType) {
    fields := strings.Split(line, "\t")

    myObject.someField = fields[0]
    myObject.anotherField = fields[1]
    (...)
    return myObject
}
```

And somewhere else I've called the original method like this:

```
readFile("path/to/file.txt", transform)
```

This gives me an error: `cannot use transform (type func(string) *MyType) as type func(string) interface {} in function argument`

Is there a different way to approach this problem in Go?

EDIT: Here's a similar but very simplified example of what I tried to do: http://play.golang.org/p/jLAsYojkII

Comment: Well, you can change transform signature to `func transform(s string) interface{}`, but I don't think it's correct and acceptable answer.

Comment: @Kavu It might work. If what you're suggesting is this: http://play.golang.org/p/V2nDekb6f5 it seems to work

Comment: @Kavu I can confirm it works. I just needed to get the output of readFile and transform it into a slice of MyType values. It's enough for me, if you want to post it as an answer, I'll be glad to accept it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change your `transform` function signature to `func transform(s string) interface{}`, but I don't think it is the best solution.

Comment: You can combine this with a type switch.